# Why does latex put the images at the end of the PDF file?

Tags: graphics, floats, epstopdf

This is really interesting. In any editor or formatting language I ever used images and text would appear in the order in which you have entered them. Not so much in LaTeX. I have a following figure:

```
Blah blah blah: 
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{image.eps}
  \caption{this is image}
\end{figure}
blah blag. Blah.
```

These are in the document headers:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile} 
\usepackage[outdir=./]{epstopdf}
```

And the image jumps to the end of the end of my PDF, leaving the text like this:

> Blah blah blah: 
>   blah blag. Blah.

Which looks stupid. The image looks stupid too, so alone at the end:

[image: image description]

1. Why does LaTeX do this and **in which cases it's a good thing**?
2. **How to prevent it** when it's **not a good thing**?

Comment: Your image is much too large for the intended position. And yes floating a picture to a better place is a good thing. http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=floats

Comment: In Word (or it's Libre Office counterpart) or HTML it would fit the place I want it to be. How is it too large? I could see PDFs with larger images between text...

Comment: LaTeX puts images exactly where you place `\includegraphics` the moving of a `figure` environment is unrelated to the image, the only purpose of that environment is to tell latex it can move it to help with page breaking. The `[htb]` option you used restricts the places the float can be placed, so makes it more likely to go to the end

Comment: Try omitting the `[htb]` location specifiers and see if that helps.

Comment: In your image the "intended position" is at the bottom of the page. And that word is not able to float a picture doesn't mean that it is a good thing. But if you want non-floating picture read the FAQ I referred (and in any case add a "p" to the float options as mentioned in the FAQ too).

Comment: @Mico nothing changed. Not even with 0.5 scale (which already makes the image hilariously small).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Red thick line marks the intended position. Isn't that clear? How can I make it more clear?

Comment: If you do not want the text to float, don't put it in a figure environment, but in that case you have to accept worse page breaks.

Comment: Sorry with "bottom" I didn't meant the last line but "quite at the bottom". There is no place for the image there.